# Can't activate SharePoint solution

Tags: 2013, solution-package

I am having a problem activating the CRM List Component for SharePoint (which is just a .wsp file). I went to Site Settings -> Web Designer Galleries -> Solutions and uploaded the solution. No problem there. Then I clicked Activate in the command bar. On the pop up window, there is an activate button, which on my first try, was clickable. I clicked it. However, the solution does not have a status of Activated.

[image]

Also, the Activate button is still enabled in the Commands bar. Deactivate is disabled. So when I click Activate to try again, this time the Activate button within the pop-up is disabled.

[image]

Can you offer any advice?

Comment: Which logs? ULS, IIS? On the SP server?

Comment: which browser you are using? did you close the browser and check back if solution is already activated? becuase it take some time to be acitvate

Comment: Check event log, then ULS on SP Server

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I tried both IE and Chrome. Neither worked. I activated the solution, went on a lunch break, came back and it still had an empty status.

Comment: did you close the browser? check the ULS logs and Event log...when you first time click on the activate.....another thing just try to delete it and readd...

Comment: are you using the correct version of CRM, their is one for 2010 and one for 2013....just making sure.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I just closed the browser and re-opened; still no activated status. I have tried deleting and re-adding the wsp before.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Yup, using the one for CRM 2013/SP 2013. Client has both. I will ask them to send the Event and ULS logs.

Comment: try to different site collection, jsut for testing.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Okay, we can try that too. Does it have to be a certain type of site collection?

Comment: check my answer, i just try to re pro the issue and i can....now i detailed the steps which required inorder to activate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant activate this solution without starting the User Code Services.Sow hen you download the solution from the [MSFT site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45018), You will get  `CRM2015-SharePointList2013-ENU-amd64.exe` file, once you extracted it you will get 3 files.

1. AllowHtcExtn.ps1
2. crmlistcomponent.wsp
3. mscrmsharepointeula

Now what should you do inorder to work.

1. Add the wsp into the site collection( which you already did)
2. Run the Powershell script on the server(AllowHtcExtn.ps1), this will

   - `Starts a user code service`. as well as
   - `Adds the .htc file extension to the list of allowed file types for the specified SharePoint 2013 Web applicatio`n.

Now you will be able to activate it.

Comment: When I ran the PowerShell script that MS provided, on my SharePoint dev server, I got this error - Cannot index into a null array.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: I m not sure about, I ran the script from browser, open the power shell console as admin...it's worked as a charm.

Comment: Okay, I ran the PowerShell console as administrator. I am now getting a new error. The starting of the User Code Service succeeds, but when it tries to enable HTC files, it says - `Cannot find an SPWebApplication object with Name, Id or Url: http://internaldev.mysite.com/sites/Dynamics%20CRM.`

Comment: Is it your webapp or code's? Also try to activate the solution as code service is runnin...

Comment: I changed the url used to just `http://internaldev.mysite.com` and it ran without errors. I'm not sure if it actually enabled HTC files correctly, but I guess that's another topic...